# Can I have multiple boolean expressions in a searched case sql statement?

Tags: sql, case

I'm trying to create a searched case sql statement based on a number of boolean expressions.

For example

```
select CASE a = b OR c = d OR e = f OR g = h
THEN 'x' ELSE 'y' END
from table_name
```

I keep getting the following error: `Incorrect syntax near '='.`

Am I doing something that's inherently wrong/illegal in sql, or is this something I can fix? If it is fixable, how can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select CASE when ( a = b OR c = d OR e = f OR g = h )
THEN 'x' ELSE 'y' END
from table_name
```

The format is `CASE..WHEN..THEN..ELSE..END`. You were just missing the `WHEN`.

Answer (score 2):

I feel really stupid. I'm missing a when after the case...

Should be

```
select CASE when a = b OR c = d OR e = f OR g = h
THEN 'x' ELSE 'y' END
from table_name
```

Then it works...

Comment: Glad you figured it out!  But you should still give credit to Yuck for providing the first correct answer.  :)

Comment: @Michael - I plan to. I upvoted him, but I can't choose his as the answer for another few minutes...

Answer (score 1):

You missed `WHEN` keyword

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN a = b OR c = d OR e = f OR g = h
THEN 'x' 
ELSE 'y' 
END
FROM table_name
```