# Why do I get syntax error Msg 156 when using CASE expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am trying to run this simple query however it doesn't even parse saying

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'between'.

Query is:

```
select  
    case DMProject.dbo.TypeFourTraining.Column2 
    when Column2 between 181 and 360 then '181-360' 
    when Column2 between 0 and 180 then '0-180' 
END as score 
from DMProject.dbo.TypeFourTraining
```

The same doesn't work for `Column2 < 360` syntax neither..

I have searched over internet from msdn, and some other sites but I see that my syntax seems to be valid, then either there is a detail I need to know or there is something I can't see :(

Can anyone please suggest a solution?

Comment: Assuming that you say *SQL* and really mean **SQL Server** - right?  **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot mix the *`simple`* and *`searched`* types of CASE expression. Remove the field name `DMProject.dbo.TypeFourTraining.Column2` specified after the CASE.

#### Correct syntax for your query:

```
SELECT  CASE 
            WHEN Column2 between 181    AND 360 THEN '181-360' 
            WHEN Column2 between 0      AND 180 THEN '0-180' 
        END as score 
FROM    DMProject.dbo.TypeFourTraining
```

### Two types of CASE expressions:

There are two types of CASE expression namely `Simple` and `Searched`. You cannot combine *Simple* and *Searched* in the same expression.

#### Simple CASE:

```
CASE input
    WHEN 1 THEN 'a'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'b'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'c'
    ELSE ''
END
```

#### Searched CASE with simple example:

```
CASE 
    WHEN input = 1 THEN 'a'
    WHEN input = 2 THEN 'b'
    WHEN input = 3 THEN 'c'
    ELSE ''
END
```

#### Searched CASE with slightly complex example:

This involves multiple columns. You can add multiple columns in each of the WHEN statements.

```
CASE 
    WHEN input = 1 AND second_column = 2 THEN 'a'
    WHEN input = 2 AND third_column  = 3 THEN 'b'
    WHEN input = 3 AND (second_column = 4 OR third_column = 6) THEN 'c'
    ELSE ''
END
```

Comment: thank you i also saw my mistake when reading this question after posting the question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877292/can-i-have-multiple-boolean-expressions-in-a-searched-case-sql-statement ..

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing up the two forms of the case statement.  Try this:

```
select (case when Column2 between 181 and 360 then '181-360' 
             when Column2 between 0 and 180 then '0-180' 
        END) as score 
from DMProject.dbo.TypeFourTraining
```

The other form would be used for singleton values:

```
select  case DMProject.dbo.TypeFourTraining.Column2 
            when 1 then '1' 
            when 2 then '2'
            etc. etc. etc. 
            END as score 
from DMProject.dbo.TypeFourTraining
```

Comment: For your second example, why not just `select case Column2`? No reason to repeat the 3-part name prefix.

Comment: I just used the naming convention of the original question.